# Oracle SQL Performance issue with 'IS NULL' - NVL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I am using Oracle 12.2 version. I have SQL that has two filter condition to fetch NULL values from huge table. i have converted that `IS NULL` to `NVL (OFF_CODE, -1)=-1` and `nvl(off_date,'01-JAN-1900')= '01-JAN-1900'`.

I have created functional based composite index on the two columns, then I taken explain plan that I pasted here. COST is reduced from 8 million to 122 now.

I was very happy after seeing this plan. but the SQL keep running for minutes. Before the change it was responding within 15 minutes. what could be the issue even after the cost is reduced the response is not quick? and how can I replace the IS NULL for better performance?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                                |     4 |   192 |   122   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                         |                                |     4 |   192 |   122   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |                                |   146 |  7008 |   121   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                        |                                |   148 |  7008 |   121   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE_NAME1                    |     4 |   128 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | INDEX_TABLE_NAME1              |     4 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | INDEX_TABLE_NAME2              |    37 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | TABLE_NAME2                    |    37 |   592 |    36   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access(NVL("OFF_CODE_ID",(-1))=(-1) AND NVL("OFF_DATE",'01-JAN-1900')='01-JAN-1900')
   6 - access("I"."ITEM_ID"="IGP"."ITEM_ID")
```

my query

```
SELECT /*+ index (i, INDEX_TABLE_NAME1)  */ 
        i.item_id,
         SUM(coalesce(igp. DEPR_cost, 0) + coalesce(igp.act_dprctn_cost, 0)) depr_cost
FROM             
    TABLE_NAME1 i,             
    TABLE_NAME2 igp       
WHERE             1 = 1             
  AND i.Item_id = igp.item_id
  AND nvl(i.off_code_id,-1) = -1 
  AND nvl(i.off_date,'01-JAN-1900') = '01-JAN-1900'
GROUP BY i.item_id;<br/>
```

My index:

```
create index INDEX_TABLE_NAME1 on TABLE_NAME1( nvl( off_code_id,-1),nvl( off_date,'01-JAN-1900'));
```

Comment: that you shouldn't have NULL values in the first place,  why not runn an update and fill all rows up, the you can check only but if itis a big table this will still take time. also have you checked the cardinality of your index?

Comment: What is your SELECT?

Comment: @nbk  Those tables are used in OLTP application , NULL values will be added on daily basis . Even running update on daily basis on Huge tale will COST the DB. Cardinality of the index is 4 .

Comment: you should use joins instead of commas, but what happens when you have a combined index on item_id and the rest

Comment: @nbk i will think of going for joins , but currently analyzing the reason for slow response despite reduced cost .  i see reduced cost but no quick response after index creation .

Comment: In most cases Oracle can not use two indexes to access a single table. Once 1st index is traversed it does not make any sense to touch 2nd index. If you filter table i on two columns you should use compound index.

Comment: Also compound index can index NULL values, so you do not have to use that NVL trick.

Comment: Do you have license for real-time SQL monitoring? You did everything right, maybe the problem is with data. INDEX RANGE SCAN traverses index from top to bottom(which is fast) and them reads leaf blocks from left to right as long as condition is met. Maybe the condition it met for nearly all rows in the table. In such a case TABLE FULL SCAN is the fastest approach. Check you data. You can also enable session trace and look in it. You will see how many blocks were read while traversing the index.

Comment: Like `select count(1) from TABLE_NAME1` ... `select count(1) from TABLE_NAME1 where off_code_id is null and  off_date is null`;

Comment: @ibre5041 Thanks for all your suggestions . 8 % of the rows are NULL in the tables for the combination of two column. That index reads 119 hundred blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can promote the use of an index if the percentage of nulls is lower than 5% on the table column(s). If that's the case you can use the second table as the driving table and write the query as:

```
select
  u.item_id,
  sum(coalesce(u.depr_cost, 0) + coalesce(u.act_dprctn_cost, 0)) as depr_cost 
from table_name1 t
join table_name2 u on u.item_id = t.item_id
where u.off_code is null
  and u.off_date is null
group by u.item_id
```

This query would benefit from the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on table_name2 (item_id, off_code, off_date);  
create index ix2 on table_name1 (item_id); -- probably already exists
```

As a side note, I fail to understand what the query is using table #1 for, since all values come from table #2. Just wondering...

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression you are only interested in the records where these two fields are NULL. Do you have other queries that filter on these columns looking for actual values? If not, why not create a filtered indexed?

```
CREATE INDEX INDEX_TABLE_NAME1_NULL_NULL on TABLE_NAME1( i.item_id) WHERE (off_code_id IS NULL AND off_date IS NULL);
```

And then change your SQL back to

```
SELECT /*+ index (i, INDEX_TABLE_NAME1)  */ 
        i.item_id,
         SUM(coalesce(igp. DEPR_cost, 0) + coalesce(igp.act_dprctn_cost, 0)) depr_cost
FROM             
    TABLE_NAME1 i,             
    TABLE_NAME2 igp       
WHERE             1 = 1             
  AND i.Item_id = igp.item_id
  AND i.off_code_id IS NULL
  AND i.off_date IS NULL
GROUP BY i.item_id;
```

Notes:

- this also avoids accidently including records that have the actual values `-1` and `1 jan 1900` in those fields
- try to use the `JOIN .. ON` construction rather than what you have now, I doubt it will make any difference in the execution plan but it's just better readable and hence less error prone IMHO.